# Identifying unknown compound using mass spectrum

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I am currently studying the textbook Mass Spectrometry - A Textbook, third edition, by Jürgen Gross. In chapter  **1.4.5 Statistical Nature of Mass Spectra**, there's a following example:

> It is important to be aware that a single molecule can only yield one ion of one $m/z$ value. This ion may either reflect the intact molecule or any of its fragment ions. Statistics on thousands of ion formations and dissociations are needed to generate a useful mass spectrum exhibiting signals at different $m/z$ where each of them can be assigned a relevant relative intensity. To understand this, simply imagine a single methane molecule that gets ionized and detected as a molecular ion: this would lead to a spectrum showing a single line at $m/z$ $16$, the intensity of which would have no meaning beyond ‘yes’ and ‘no’ (Fig. 1.7a). Alternatively, the molecular ion might fragment to yield a single $\ce{CH3+}$ ion at $m/z$ $15$; again, the spectrum would show only one line. In fact, such a spectrum could not tell us whether the peak is caused by a molecular or a fragment ion. Eight ions might lead to a spectrum where each ion corresponds to $33.3 \%$ relative intensity (as in Fig. 1.7c) even though other distributions would be possible. Eleven ions could scale the intensity in $20\%$ steps, while 23 ions could lead to a spectrum with $10\%$ steps. It is evident that a spectrum with intensity levels as accurate as $0.1\%$ has to be based on thousands of ions (Fig. 1.7f).

> [image]

Reading this, I do not understand how the author used this mass spectrum to infer that the molecule in question is $\ce{CH3+}$. The author seems to imply that, given this mass spectrum ($m/z$ values of $16$, $15$, etc.), we are able to infer that the molecule is $\ce{CH3+}$, but he doesn't really explain how this is done.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain how the author identified $\ce{CH3+}$.

Comment: So what atom is the mathematical difference between 44 and 28? Then identify 28.

Comment: It seems you have trouble to fit our Q&A model. Usually 2 questions is one too many. In this case, if you don't get the spectrum of methane, there's IMO like no chance to solve this monster you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @user55119 I've cut it out, for more focus.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, I assume that if I understand the methane case, then I'll be able to understand the other case.

Comment: @user55119 Well, we can see that the difference is 16, but what can we infer from this? That there is an oxygen molecule present (since it has atomic mass of 16)?

Comment: If it is oxygen, then what is 28?

Comment: @user55119 I'm not sure. Maybe we next consider that 28 - 22 = 6, but then what is 6? This just seems like guesswork. Surely analyzing mass spectra is not done in this way? It seems very "hand-wavy".

Comment: Focus on the 4 strongest peaks, 12, 16, 28 and 44. Peak 22 (m/2z) is a doubly charged 44 ( m/z). Look here: https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Mask=200#Mass-Spec

Comment: @user55119 Ahh, I understand now! The lowest peaks are 12 (carbon) and 16 (oxygen), so 28 = 12 + 16; and 28 + 16 (oxygen) = 44, so we have $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: Yup! The 28 peak is CO. The peak 29 is C(13)O. Peak 45 is O=C(13)=O and peak 46 is O=C=O(18). Natural abundance of C13 = 1.1%; O18 = 0.2%.

Comment: @user55119 Ok, thanks for taking the time to clarify this.